Realice un Programa en C++ que lea de entrada dos enteros y muestre cual de estos es mas largo. Verificar si el usuario ingreso un tipo de dato entero
El programa en si es sencillo, lograr ver cual de los dos enteros ingresados es mas largo. Esto lo logre con el uso de un ciclo while en donde se divide cada numero entre 10 hasta obtener un solo digito, guardando asi el numero de iteraciones en una variable. Ahora, el programa requiere que verifique si el numero ingresado por el usuario es un dato de tipo entero, con el uso de excepciones (Try/Catch), y si es posible que limpie la variable y se la vuelva a pedir al usuario. Como lo podría realizar? El código es el siguiente:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num1, num2, long1=1, long2=1;

    cout << "Ingrese el primer numero: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Ingrese el segundo numero: ";
    cin >> num2;

    while(num1>=10){
        num1 = num1/10;
        long1++;
    }
    while(num2>=10){
        num2 = num2/10;
        long2++;
    }

    cout << "Cifras 1: " << long1 << endl;
    cout << "Cifras 2: " << long2 << endl;

    return 0;
}


La lectura del entero no genera ninguna excepción. Si falla establece el bit de fallo del stream y no modifica la variable en la que se guardaría el valor.
Puedes verificar que la lectura fue correcta mediante la conversión implícita a bool o la función good.
En el caso de que haya ocurrido un error, es necesario reestablecer el estado del stream con la función clear antes de seguir leyendo.
El código sería bastante simple:
while (!(cin >> num1)) {
    cout << "Ingresa un número válido";
    cin.clear();
}

Pero con excepciones, debes crear una función como la siguiente:
int leer(){
    int n;
    if (cin >> n)
        return n;

    cin.clear();
    throw runtime_error("No es un número");
}

Luego la atrapas y haces lo que tengas que hacer. Por ejemplo:
while (true) {
    try {
        num1 = leer();
        break;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e){
        ...
    }
}


Para obtener los dígitos de un número no tienes que hacer algo tan complicado como un bucle dividiendo entre 10.
Usa un logaritmo:
std::cout << int(std::log10(99999) + 1); // Muestra 5.
std::cout << int(std::log10(11111) + 1); // Muestra 5.

Para pedir datos sin parar hasta que se cumpla una condición, usa un bucle, y para saber si has leído un número comprueba si std::cin equivale a false tras la lectura:
int digitos(int numero)
{
    return std::log10(numero) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int numeros[2]{};

    for (int id = 0; id != 2; ) try
    {
        if (!(std::cin >> numeros[id]))
            throw std::invalid_argument{"Eso no es un numero."};

        std::cout
            << "El numero " << numeros[id]
            << " tiene " << digitos(numeros[id])
            << " digitos\n";

        ++id;
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }

    return 0;
}

Puedes ver el código funcionando en Try it online!.
